# Retrieve string data stored in integer field from sqlite 3 database using C#

Tags: c#, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I have an sqlite3 database with several tables. One of them has two fields: s_id and user_id, the first is integer, the second is integer primary key.
I can watch the table contents with SQLite Data Browser,and there are two rows in the table.

user_id values are 1 and 2.

s_id values are, however, strings (like "user1" and "user2"), and sqlite data browser shows these strings.

I am trying to retreive the information using System.Data.SQLite and the following code in C#:

```csh
using (SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(string.Format(@"Data Source={0};Legacy Format=True;", path)))
{
  connection.Open();
  using (SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT * FROM users", connection))
  {
    using (SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
      while (reader.Read())
      {
       string user = reader["s_id"].ToString();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I searched the internet and found that sqlite can store string data in int fields. But I cannot read these strings using C#. The result is always "0". Even if I expand the reader in the Watch till I'll be able to see the objects, the value there is 0 too. (The second object corresponding to user_id has value as it should have, 1 or 2).

Do you know how this string value in integer field can be retrieved in C#?

Thank you.

Comment: if you are only checking for s_id, why are you doing a select * for starters... 2nd where are you storing the connection string.. if it's in a .config file ...why not just pass that value in your Connection Object...? 3rd.. wrap this code around a Try Catch{} so that if you have an exception ...you can also post it here...

Comment: You can search the stored data values.. I am wondering what are you using the string user variable for.. if you are to store it, then you are overriding it because you are setting the string user = ..... in the while loop.. if you want to store it in 2 different variables then you need to add a second variable to store it in within the while loop

Comment: @DJKRAZE: The problem here isn't an exception but the problem that C# can't cast "user1" (and other strings) to int, what sqlite happily does, and therefore the returned value is always 0

Comment: @DJKRAZE I posted only the code that concerns the problem I need to solve. Of course I do not declare string user inside the loop in my actual code, I just see no sense in complicating the code posted here.

Comment: @Tobias Thanks, you are absolutely right. I get no exceptions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First things first: If you're going to store *TypeX* in a database column, don't declare it as *TypeY*, just because you can. Storing only values of the appropriate type is (as far as sqlite is concerned) essential for being technology independent (as you can see).

If, for some weird reason, you aren't able to change the database itself, you should cast the value in your query, like this:

```sql
SELECT CAST(s_id AS VARCHAR(255)) AS s_id FROM users;
```

Comment: If it was my database, of course I wouldn't have used integer field to store string. But it is not mine.
Thanks, it solves the problem - I actually didn't think of using a different query string.